# Label Encoder functionality in R?

Tags: r

In python, scikit has a great function called [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) that maps categorical levels (strings) to integer representation.

*Is there anything in R to do this*? For example if there is a variable called color with values {'Blue','Red','Green'} the encoder would translate:

```
Blue => 1
Green => 2
Red => 3
```

and create an object with this mapping to then use for transforming new data in a similar fashion.

**Add:**
It doesn't seem like just factors will work because there is no persisting of the mapping. If the new data has an unseen level from the training data, the entire structure changes. Ideally I would like the new levels labeled missing or 'other' somehow.

```
sample_dat <- data.frame(a_str=c('Red','Blue','Blue','Red','Green'))
sample_dat$a_int<-as.integer(as.factor(sample_dat$a_str))
sample_dat$a_int
#[1] 3 1 1 3 2
sample_dat2 <- data.frame(a_str=c('Red','Blue','Blue','Red','Green','Azure'))
sample_dat2$a_int<-as.integer(as.factor(sample_dat2$a_str))
sample_dat2$a_int
# [1] 4 2 2 4 3 1
```

Comment: Factors in R are coded as integers. Not sure what exactly your "requirements" are.

Comment: Will factors act as a consistent indexing of strings to integers for future data? I will show an example in my question

Comment: They can if you explicitly list the levels the factor can hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following which I think works, the efficiency of which and/or how it will scale is not yet tested

```
str2Int.fit_transform<-function(df, plug_missing=TRUE){

  list_of_levels=list()  #empty list   

  #loop through the columns
  for (i in 1: ncol(df))
  {

    #only   
    if (is.character(df[,i]) ||  is.factor(df[,i]) ){

      #deal with missing
      if(plug_missing){

        #if factor
        if (is.factor(df[,i])){
          df[,i] = factor(df[,i], levels=c(levels(df[,i]), 'MISSING'))
          df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] = 'MISSING' 


        }else{   #if character

          df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] = 'MISSING' 

        }
      }#end missing IF

      levels<-unique(df[,i]) #distinct levels
      list_of_levels[[colnames(df)[i]]] <- levels #set list with name of the columns to the levels
      df[,i] <- as.numeric(factor(df[,i], levels = levels))

    }#end if character/factor IF


  }#end loop

  return (list(list_of_levels,df)) #return the list of levels and the new DF

}#end of function



str2Int.transform<-function(df,list_of_levels,plug_missing=TRUE)
{
  #loop through the columns
  for (i in 1: ncol(df))
  {

    #only   
    if (is.character(df[,i]) ||  is.factor(df[,i]) ){


      #deal with missing
      if(plug_missing){

        #if factor
        if (is.factor(df[,i])){
          df[,i] = factor(df[,i], levels=c(levels(df[,i]), 'MISSING'))
          df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] = 'MISSING' 


        }else{   #if character

          df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] = 'MISSING' 

        }
      }#end missing IF

      levels=list_of_levels[[colnames(df)[i]]]

      if (! is.null(levels)){
        df[,i] <- as.numeric(factor(df[,i], levels = levels))
      }

    }# character or factor

  }#end of loop

  return(df)

}#end of function




######################################################
# Test the functions
######################################################



###Test fit transform

# as strings
sample_dat <- data.frame(a_fact=c('Red','Blue','Blue',NA,'Green'), a_int=c(1,2,3,4,5), a_str=c('a','b','c','a','v'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

result<-str2Int.fit_transform(sample_dat)
result[[1]] #list of levels
result[[2]] #transformed df

#as factors
sample_dat <- data.frame(a_fact=c('Red','Blue','Blue',NA,'Green'), a_int=c(1,2,3,4,5), a_str=c('a','b','c','a','v'),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

result<-str2Int.fit_transform(sample_dat)
result[[1]] #list of levels
result[[2]] #transformed df



###Test transform
str2Int.transform(sample_dat,result[[1]])
```

Comment: Most importantly, your solution works for cases where the input has incomplete, new, and missing data. Great work.  I tested with this: `new_dat <- data.frame(a_fact=c('Green','purple', 'Blue'), 
                      a_int=c(1,2, 3), 
                      a_str=c('z', 'a', NA),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE) ;
str2Int.transform(new_dat, result[[1]]) ;
#   a_fact a_int a_str
# 1      4     1    NA
# 2     NA     2     1
# 3      2     3    NA` (which is hard to read.. but it's right)

Comment: I made some changes and added some tests / examples.  I'll be using this in geneorama (my personal package) for sure. The only other thing I want is a way to generate the output matrix with indicator variables.  Shouldn't be too hard though. https://gist.github.com/geneorama/02e4e6edb2070d8873377e09d3ecc5d9

Answer (score 11):

Create your vector of data:

```
colors <- c("red", "red", "blue", "green")
```

Create a factor:

```
factors <- factor(colors)
```

Convert the factor to numbers:

```
as.numeric(factors)
```

Output: (note that this is in alphabetical order)

```
# [1] 3 3 1 2
```

You can also set a custom numbering system: (note that the output now follows the "rainbow color order" that I defined)

```
rainbow <- c("red","orange","yellow","green","blue","purple")
ordered <- factor(colors, levels = rainbow)
as.numeric(ordered)
# [1] 1 1 5 4
```

See `?factor`.

Comment: This seems to work well. I am wondering if there are any libraries that have create the processing steps already (Caret does not) or it needs to be coded from scratch (to transform initially and also create the dictionary for applying the coding later).

Comment: How to do back mapping? Like in first example, if I send 3 then I should get "red". How would that be possible? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Try [CatEncoders](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CatEncoders/CatEncoders.pdf) package. It replicates the Python `sklearn.preprocessing` functionality.

```
# variable to encode values
colors = c("red", "red", "blue", "green")
lab_enc = LabelEncoder.fit(colors)

# new values are transformed to NA
values = transform(lab_enc, c('red', 'red', 'yellow'))
values

# [1]  3  3 NA


# doing the inverse: given the encoded numbers return the labels
inverse.transform(lab_enc, values)
# [1] "red" "red" NA
```

I would add the functionality of reporting the non-matching labels with a warning.

PS: It also has the `OneHotEncoder` function.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

If I correctly understand what do you want:

```
# function which returns function which will encode vectors with values  of 'vec' 
label_encoder = function(vec){
    levels = sort(unique(vec))
    function(x){
        match(x, levels)
    }
}

colors = c("red", "red", "blue", "green")

color_encoder = label_encoder(colors) # create encoder

encoded_colors = color_encoder(colors) # encode colors
encoded_colors

new_colors = c("blue", "green", "green")  # new vector
encoded_new_colors = color_encoder(new_colors)
encoded_new_colors

other_colors = c("blue", "green", "green", "yellow") 
color_encoder(other_colors) # NA's are introduced

# save and restore to disk
saveRDS(color_encoder, "color_encoder.RDS")
c_encoder = readRDS("color_encoder.RDS")
c_encoder(colors) # same result

# dealing with multiple columns

# create data.frame
set.seed(123) # make result reproducible
color_dataframe = as.data.frame(
    matrix(
        sample(c("red", "blue", "green",  "yellow"), 12, replace = TRUE),
        ncol = 3)
)
color_dataframe

# encode each column
for (column in colnames(color_dataframe)){
    color_dataframe[[column]] = color_encoder(color_dataframe[[column]])
}
color_dataframe
```

Comment: Wow....I wish I understood what this was doing, but seems to work. Is it possible to run though with multiple columns (apply) and persist the objects to disk for later encoding?

Comment: @B_Miner See my additions to answer

Comment: Very impressive! Can you tell me a sketch of how the nested function works?

Comment: @B_Miner R has lexical scoping. It means that each created encoder will "see" its own `levels` variable which was in enclosing encoder environment. You can read about scoping in more details in the excellent Hadley Wickham's guide: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Comment: Feels like this function is close but what it needs is probably a way to deal with each column individually. So that the mapping between each string and int is distinct per column. I probably did not describe well enough the requirement. If you are interested I could start another question.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to believe why no one has mentioned `caret`'s `dummyVars` function.

This is a widely searched question, and people don't want to write their own methods or copy and paste other users methods, they want a *package*, and `caret` is the closest thing to `sklearn` in R.

EDIT: I now realize that what the user actually want's is to turn strings into a counting number, which is just `as.numeric(as.factor(x))` but I'm going to leave this here because using hot-one encoding is the more accurate method of encoding categorical data.

Answer (score 0):

```
# input P to the function below is a dataframe containing only categorical variables
numlevel <- function(P) { 

n <- dim(P)[2]

for(i in 1: n) {

  m <- length(unique(P[[i]]))

levels(P[[i]]) <- c(1:m)

}

return(P)

}

Q <- numlevel(P)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df<- mtcars

head(df)

df$cyl  <- factor(df$cyl)

df$carb <- factor(df$carb)
vec <- sapply(df, is.factor)

catlevels <- sapply(df[vec], levels)

#store the levels for each category
#level appearing first is coded as 1, second as 2 so on

df <- sapply(df, as.numeric)

class(df) #matrix

df <- data.frame(df) 

#converting back to dataframe

head(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Data
Country <- c("France", "Spain", "Germany", "Spain", "Germany", "France")
Age <- c(34, 27, 30, 32, 42, 30)
Purchased <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes")
df <- data.frame(Country, Age, Purchased)
df

# Output
  Country Age Purchased
1  France  34        No
2   Spain  27       Yes
3 Germany  30        No
4   Spain  32        No
5 Germany  42       Yes
6  France  30       Yes
```

Using CatEncoders package : Encoders for Categorical Variables

```
library(CatEncoders)

# Saving names of categorical variables
factors <- names(which(sapply(df, is.factor)))

# Label Encoder
for (i in factors){
  encode <- LabelEncoder.fit(df[, i])
  df[, i] <- transform(encode, df[, i])
}
df

# Output
  Country Age Purchased
1       1  34         1
2       3  27         2
3       2  30         1
4       3  32         1
5       2  42         2
6       1  30         2
```

Using R base : factor function

```
# Label Encoder
levels <- c("France", "Spain", "Germany", "No", "Yes")
labels <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
for (i in factors){
  df[, i] <- factor(df[, i], levels = levels, labels = labels, ordered = TRUE)
}
df

# Output
  Country Age Purchased
1       1  34         1
2       2  27         2
3       3  30         1
4       2  32         1
5       3  42         2
6       1  30         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **easy** and **neat** solution:

From the superml package:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/superml/versions/0.5.3
There is a LabelEncoder class:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/superml/versions/0.5.3/topics/LabelEncoder

```
install.packages("superml")
library(superml)

lbl <- LabelEncoder$new()
lbl$fit(sample_dat$column)
sample_dat$column <- lbl$fit_transform(sample_dat$column)
decode_names <- lbl$inverse_transform(sample_dat$column)
```